# My Script for Rock Paper Scissors isn't working. Console logs: Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'playerSelection' has already been declared

Tags: javascript

I just started learning javaScript and my first proyect is to make a Rock Paper Scissors game that plays on the console, the code that I wrote is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>

    let RPS = function playRound (playerSelection, computerSelection) {

    let playerSelection = promt ("What do you choose?", "");

    let computerSelection = math.Random ();
        if computerSelection (<0.34) {
            computerSelection = "Rock";
        } else if computerSelection (>=0.35 && <=0.66) {
                computerSelection = "Paper";
        } else {
                computerSelection = "Scissors";
        }

    if (playerSelection === "Rock"){
        if (computerSelection === "Scissors") {
            console.log ("You win");
        } else {
            console.log ("You lose");
        }
    }    
    if (playerSelection === "Paper") {
        if (computerSelection === "Scissors"){
            console.log ("You win");
        }else {
            console.log ("You lose")
        }    
    }
    if (playerSelection === "Scissors") {
        if (computerSelection ==== "Paper"){
            console.log ("You win")
        } else {
            console.log ("You lose")
        }
    }

    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to run this on the console I get

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'playerSelection' has already been declared
```

Why is that?

Comment: Because it has already been declared in the function arguments

Comment: Not that it's the cause of the issue, but I think "promt" (line 8) should be "prompt".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is very straight forward. You are passing arguments named `playerSelection` and `computerSelection` then you immediately try to declare two local variables of the same name - however, arguments are considered local variables themselves, so you are indeed duplicating. Either pass the variables to the function as arguments or declare them in the code using `let`, not both.

Additionally, your code is riddled with syntax errors, you definitely need to proof-read this code because it will not run even if you fix the issue you ask about in the question.

Here is an example of what you probably want:

```js
let RPS = function playRound() {
  let playerSelection = prompt("What do you choose?", "");
  let computerSelection = Math.random();

  if (computerSelection < 0.34) {
    computerSelection = "Rock";
  } else if (computerSelection >= 0.35 && computerSelection <= 0.66) {
    computerSelection = "Paper";
  } else {
    computerSelection = "Scissors";
  }

  if (playerSelection === "Rock") {
    if (computerSelection === "Scissors") {
      console.log("You win");
    } else {
      console.log("You lose");
    }
  }
  if (playerSelection === "Paper") {
    if (computerSelection === "Scissors") {
      console.log("You win");
    } else {
      console.log("You lose")
    }
  }
  if (playerSelection === "Scissors") {
    if (computerSelection === "Paper") {
      console.log("You win")
    } else {
      console.log("You lose")
    }
  }
}

RPS()
```